# Can I use jQuery to surround an element with <form></form>?

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="modal" ><div class="modal-window">
<ul class="action-tabs right">
<li><a href="#" title="Close window">
<img src="/Content/images/icons/fugue/cross-circle.png" width="16" height="16"></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="block-content"><h1>xx</h1>
<div class="modal-content>
...
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I can't change the way this is coded but I need there to be a form element starting after the h1 heading and finishing after the end div of the class "modal-content". Note there's only one "block-content" and "modal-content".

Is there a way using jQuery that I could insert in a form tag as below:

```
<div id="modal" ><div class="modal-window">
<ul class="action-tabs right">
<li><a href="#" title="Close window">
<img src="/Content/images/icons/fugue/cross-circle.png" width="16" height="16"></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="block-content"><h1>xx</h1>
<form id="xx">
<div class="modal-content>
...
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this ..

```
$(".modal-content").wrap("<form id='xx'>")
```

Refer http://api.jquery.com/wrap/ for more options

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.modal-content').wrap('<form id="xx"></form>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use one of the wrap-functions: http://api.jquery.com/?s=wrap

```
$( '.modal-content' ).wrapAll( '<form />' );
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple example

```
$(".modal-content").wrap('<form id="xx"></form>');
```

See http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, easilly:

```
$('.modal-content').wrap('<form id="xxx" />');
```

Read more on `.wrap()` here: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/