# How do I create a Div around this append line?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line of jQuery:

`$('.object1').append('<a href="   ' + linkURL +  '   "> ' + headlineText +  '</a>');`

This creates a link on the website.

I want to then take that created link and **wrap it in a div** specific to it, with class name "linkdiv".

Any ideas? Am lost.

Comment: read up on `document.createElement`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475321/can-i-use-jquery-to-surround-an-element-with-form-form

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use jQuery to surround an element with <form></form>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475321/can-i-use-jquery-to-surround-an-element-with-form-form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap `div` around `a` in string parameter or you can use [`wrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function.

```js
const linkURL = "someUrl";
const headlineText = "someText";
$('.object1').append('<div class="linkdiv"><a href="   ' + linkURL +  '   ">' + headlineText +  '</a></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="object1">Here:</div>
```

Vanilla JS (without jQuery) solution:

```js
const linkURL = "someUrl";
const headlineText = "someText";

// create div
const divEl = document.createElement("div");
divEl.classList.add("linkdiv");

// create link
const linkEl = document.createElement("a");
linkEl.href = linkURL;
linkEl.innerHTML = headlineText;

// append link to div
divEl.append(linkEl);

// append div to body
document.body.append(divEl);
```

Comment: This works extremely well. Thank you very much. I will accept as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at jquerys [wrap method](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

In your case:

```
$('.object1')
  .append('<a href="   ' + linkURL +  '   "> ' + headlineText +  '</a>')
  .wrap("<div class='linkdiv'></div>");
```